# In which extent can I use the Oracle Data Provider for .NET Managed Driver?

Tags: oracle-11g, oracle-12c, c#, license, odp.net

Good evening everybody,

I am planing to dive into the oracle database world. Additionally, I want to develop some tools, which make my life easy by checking and modifying information in different tables.

Since I would develop the tools in C#, I found the Oracle Data Provider for .NET Managed Driver, which seems to be really nice.

Before using it, I have some questions:

- Is it free to use?
  Regarding to the license (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/distribution-license-152002.html), I should be able to use the managed driver. Or do I interpret it in a wrong way?

For me it is not clear, if I could also use my tools at customer side? Or could I give the tool to some customer to help him or does it lead to a license problem already?
What about selling the tool? For me it is hard to interpret the answers from the license text.

I hope you can help me.

Best regards
Seth

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle Data Provider for .NET FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/faq-093106.html#distribute)

> **Q: I bundle ODP.NET with an application I've built, which I want to distribute or sell. Does Oracle charge licensing fees for this?**
>
> A: In most cases, Oracle does not charge any fees for distributing the
>   Oracle client nor ODP.NET with a third-party application. However, it
>   is best to consult the licensing agreement from which you acquired
>   rights to the Oracle software. If you purchased Oracle licenses
>   directly from Oracle, consult your Oracle licensing contract or your
>   Oracle sales representative. If you downloaded ODP.NET from OTN,
>   consult the licensing agreement that you agreed to prior to
>   downloading the software.

Comment: You post sounds like I can use my own tools, which would use the odp.net managed driver, for my self, at the company I am working for and at customer side without hurting any license. Regarding your post it seems like I could even sell it without hurting any license. But regarding to [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/distribution-license-152002.html) it is hard to say (at least for me), if I can do all those things without hurting the license.

Comment: Do you know, if I can use this managed driver for free or do I need to buy any license? Based on my [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/distribution-license-152002.html), do you think I could use my tools, which would use the odp.net managed driver, the at the company I am working for and also at customer side? What about selling? It would be really nice, if you could share your thoughts about my questions.